# face-recognition de Python no reconoce los rostros cuadn oestan lejos

Tags: python, opencv

Mi codigo lo saque de esta pagina: https://robologs.net/2020/05/05/deteccion-y-reconocimiento-facial-con-opencv-python-y-facerecognition/

Uso este:

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
 
"""
    Código 2.2 - Reconocimiento facial con webcam
    Este código identifica nuestro rostro en un vídeo capturado con una webcam.
 
    Escrito por Glare y Transductor
    www.robologs.net
"""
 
 
import cv2
import face_recognition
 
 
#Cargar la imagen de ejemplo con nuestro rostro:
imagen_personal = face_recognition.load_image_file("foto_personal.jpg")
 
#Extraer los 'encodings' que caracterizan nuestro rostro:
personal_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(imagen_personal)[0]
 
#Definir un array con los encodings y nuestro nombre:
encodings_conocidos = [
    personal_encodings
]
nombres_conocidos = [
    "Soy yo :)"
]
# NOTA: Como solo queremos identificarnos a nosotros mismos, en realidad no sería necesario definir un array.
# Lo he hecho así para imitar la estructura del código del ejemplo anterior, y para que sea fácil añadir
# nuevos rostros (vuestra pareja o hijos, por ejemplo).
 
 
#Iniciar la webcam:
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# NOTA: Si no funciona puedes cambiar el índice '0' por otro, o cambiarlo por la dirección de tu webcam.
 
 
#Cargar una fuente de texto:
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX
 
 
# Identificar rostros es un proceso costoso. Para poder hacerlo en tiempo real sin que haya retardo
# vamos a reducir el tamaño de la imagen de la webcam. Esta variable 'reduccion' indica cuanto se va a reducir:
reduccion = 5 #Con un 5, la imagen se reducirá a 1/5 del tamaño original
 
 
#Recordamos al usuario cuál es la tecla para salir:
print("\nRecordatorio: pulsa 'ESC' para cerrar.\n")
 
 
while 1:
    #Definimos algunos arrays y variables:
    loc_rostros = [] #Localizacion de los rostros en la imagen
    encodings_rostros = [] #Encodings de los rostros
    nombres_rostros = [] #Nombre de la persona de cada rostro
    nombre = "" #Variable para almacenar el nombre
 
    #Capturamos una imagen con la webcam:
    valido, img = webcam.read()
 
    #Si la imagen es válida (es decir, si se ha capturado correctamente), continuamos:
    if valido:
 
        #La imagen está en el espacio de color BGR, habitual de OpenCV. Hay que convertirla a RGB:
        img_rgb = img[:, :, ::-1]
 
        #Reducimos el tamaño de la imagen para que sea más rápida de procesar:
        img_rgb = cv2.resize(img_rgb, (0, 0), fx=1.0/reduccion, fy=1.0/reduccion)
 
        #Localizamos cada rostro de la imagen y extraemos sus encodings:
        loc_rostros = face_recognition.face_locations(img_rgb)
        encodings_rostros = face_recognition.face_encodings(img_rgb, loc_rostros)
 
        #Recorremos el array de encodings que hemos encontrado:
        for encoding in encodings_rostros:
 
            #Buscamos si hay alguna coincidencia con algún encoding conocido:
            coincidencias = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodings_conocidos, encoding)
 
            #El array 'coincidencias' es ahora un array de booleanos. Si contiene algun 'True', es que ha habido alguna coincidencia:
            if True in coincidencias:
                nombre = nombres_conocidos[coincidencias.index(True)]
 
            #Si no hay ningún 'True' en el array 'coincidencias', no se ha podido identificar el rostro:
            else:
                nombre = "???"
 
            #Añadir el nombre de la persona identificada en el array de nombres:
            nombres_rostros.append(nombre)
 
        #Dibujamos un recuadro rojo alrededor de los rostros desconocidos, y uno verde alrededor de los conocidos:
        for (top, right, bottom, left), nombre in zip(loc_rostros, nombres_rostros):
             
            #Deshacemos la reducción de tamaño para tener las coordenadas de la imagen original:
            top = top*reduccion
            right = right*reduccion
            bottom = bottom*reduccion
            left = left*reduccion
 
            #Cambiar de color según si se ha identificado el rostro:
            if nombre != "???":
                color = (0,255,0)
            else:
                color = (0,0,255)
 
            #Dibujar un rectángulo alrededor de cada rostro identificado, y escribir el nombre:
            cv2.rectangle(img, (left, top), (right, bottom), color, 2)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (left, bottom - 20), (right, bottom), color, -1)
            cv2.putText(img, nombre, (left, bottom - 6), font, 0.6, (0,0,0), 1)
 
        #Mostrar el resultado en una ventana:
        cv2.imshow('Output', img)
 
        #Salir con 'ESC'
        k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
        if k == 27:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
 
webcam.release()
```

El rostro se detecta perfectamente, ese no es el problema, el problema es que no lo detecta cuando esta lejos. Mi camara tiene buena calidad (2K), pero, supongo que el problema no es la calidad. Asi que mi pregunta es: Sabes como hacer que facereognition de Python reconozca rostros a distancia?

AQui esta el pip: https://pypi.org/project/face-recognition/

Comment: Eso tiene que ver con el algoritmo y si solo copiaste y pegaste el código y no sabes como funciona, creo que poco podrás hacer

Comment: Entiendo el codigo, pero, no se sobre la distancia. Los rostros harrcascade de Opencv se reconocen a distancia, con face_recognition (el argoritmo que coloque) no, me gustaria saber si se puede mejorar.

Comment: Una alternativa que se me ocurrio fue la de cortar el rostro con opencv y lego pasarselo a face_recognition, pero, no seria tan elegante como que face_recognition pueda analizar el rostro a distancia.

Comment: Creo que deberas cambiar o agregar más datos de entrenamientos